# How to convert Csv File to nested Json using Nifi?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-nifi

I am converting CSV File file to json in a nested format. How Can I convert my csv to required json in nifi? There is alot of list and array thing.

Assume CSV FILE like this

| Agent | Location | Company | Model1 | Sub-Model1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | L1 | Hyundai | Verna | 2018 |
| A1 | L1 | Hyundai | creta | 2015 |
| A1 | L1 | Hyundai | Aura | 2022 |
| A2 | L1 | Toyota | Fortuner | 2020 |

Required JSON Nested format

```
[
{"Agent":"A1",
  "loc_id":"L1",
   "Company":{ 
        "Hyundai":[ {"Verna":[
                              {
                               "2018":[]
                              }
                             ]
                    },
                    {"Creta":[
                              {
                                "2015":[]
                              }
                             ]
                    },
                    {"Aura":[
                              {
                               "2022":[]
                              }
                             ]
                    }
                ]
             }
},
{"Agent":"A2",
 "loc_id":"L1",
 "Company":{
             "Toyota":[
                      {
                       "Fortuner":[
                                  {
                                    "2020":[]
                                  }
                                  ]
                      }
                      ]
           }
}
]
```

Comment: Here is a link to an article: https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/read-csv-files-and-convert-data-into-json-format-using-nifi-controller-services

Answer (score 0):

What you could transform the CSV to JSON using the ConvertRecord Processor and then use something like JOLT to transform the data to the proper format. https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Or you could write a script to do it.